# Anyone knows how to login with linkdIn using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LinkdIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onLinkedInLoad = this.onLinkedInLoad.bind(this);
    this.getProfileData = this.getProfileData.bind(this);
    this.displayProfileData = this.displayProfileData.bind(this);
    this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
  }

  // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
  getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Profile("me")
      .fields(
        "id",
        "first-name",
        "last-name",
        "headline",
        "location",
        "picture-url",
        "public-profile-url",
        "email-address"
      )
      .result(displayProfileData)
      .error(onError);
  }

  // Handle the successful return from the API call
  displayProfileData(data) {
    var user = data.values[0];
    alert(user.emailAddress);
    alert(user.pictureUrl);
    alert(user.lastName);
    alert(user.headline);
    alert(user.location.name);
    alert(user.publicProfileUrl);
  }

  // Handle an error response from the API call
  onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  // Destroy the session of linkedin
  logout() {
    IN.User.logout(removeProfileData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onLinkedInLoad}> Login with LinkdIn </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default LinkdIn;
```

> Errors :
>
> ./src/Components/LinkdIn.js   Line 24:  'IN' is not defined
>   no-undef   Line 24:  'IN' is not defined                  no-undef
>   Line 24:  'getProfileData' is not defined      no-undef   Line 31: 
>   'IN' is not defined                  no-undef   Line 31: 
>   'displayProfileData' is not defined  no-undef   Line 31:  'onError' is
>   not defined             no-undef   Line 53:  'IN' is not defined
>   no-undef   Line 53:  'removeProfileData' is not defined   no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: This looks like linter errors. Do you have `IN` as a global variable?

Comment: No i don't understand this error

Comment: Logging into LinkedIn isn't a React problem, but rather logging in from the client with JavaScript. You are trying to use undefined variables which suggests you need to learn some basics first!

Comment: can you please fix this code for me

Comment: There is no way to fix the code for you in such case. What is `IN`? You calling the method `onLinkedInLoad` and `IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);` So what is `IN`?

Comment: i am stuck right now :/ what can i do ?

Comment: @MuqeetGhouri Follow the instructions [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#).